# Problems Building solution with TeamCity (possible nuget-issue)

Tags: c#, build, teamcity, nuget

I try to build a solution with TeamCity. To reduce our repository-size, wie do NOT include DLLs into the repository, but use NuGet to receive the current actual version of any package when building the solution.
We can build the solution on our local machines but receive an error on the TeamCity-Buildserver:

```
The type or namespace name 'Formatting' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I *think* there is a problem with the nuget-packages. System.Net.Http.Formatting should be in the NuGet-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.0.0 which IS downloaded by Teamcity. But it seems that the build command (Microsoft Visual Studio solution runner) looks into the Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.xx instead where is no "formatting"-namespace

This is just my guess, what is going wrong. Any clue how to fix this issue?

My Packages-Configuration:

```
<packages>
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.10" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http.Formatting" version="4.0.20505.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Are you maybe experiencing this bug?: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3521

Comment: No. Thats not the issue

Comment: Try find the root cause error; search the log for "Could not resolve this reference". May be caused because of a target framework mismatch or something else. Post root cause here.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Jack. I solved this annoying problem. Don't know if its the "golden" solution, but it works.

Comment: Could you post your packages configuration? Is it possible that you're actually specifying a minimum version which is inappropriate? (Your dev machines may have picked up the latest version, which you actually need, but your build server is using an older version.) If you check out your solution on a *clean* developer machine and use that to restore packages from NuGet, does that work? I'm assuming you're still interested in a cleaner approach :)

Comment: The solution builds on many dev machines. So I do not expect the conf to be corrupt. I updated my question with the packages.conf BEFORE I did what I mentioned in the answer. And yes, you are right: I AM very interested in a cleaner approack :)

Comment: Just deleted my answer. Solved the build-issue, but threw exceptions on running

Comment: Ok. I threw away the "suspicious" package. It is now running. Because I tried that much I can't be exactly sure what was the solution, but my best guess would be removing the "update packaged" - option and installing the "WebApi 2.1 Client Libraries". Thank you all so much (and especially @JonSkeet to force me to find a cleaner solution :)

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways to do package restore.  The older way involved having a .nuget folder alongside your solution with nuget.exe and nuget.targets there and a nuget.config file alongside your .sln file.  This is typically enabled by right clicking on your solution file and hitting 'Enable Package Restore'.

The newer approach does not involve modifying the build process, but instead Visual Studio takes care of package restore.  You don't need to enable it.  I think it's on by default unless you've used the older approach.  This new approach is great when you're building in VS, but when using TeamCity, you'll need to modify your build process.

Check which approach your using (the newer one wouldn't add a nuget.exe in {solution root}/.nuget).  If you're using the newer one, you'd want to add a separate command-line step to your build process to call this.  It will populate the packages folder with everything the build will need to succeed.  Provided you didn't manually change references, the hint path on those references should point to the appropriate places (If you did, you can run Update-Package PackageName -Reinstall -ProjectName WhicheverProjectYouModified from the package manager console).

```
c:\somewhere\nuget.exe restore c:\somewhere\yoursolution.sln
```

This will require you to put a recent version of nuget.exe somewhere on your build server.  If you already have nuget there somewhere, run this to bring it to the latest version:

```
nuget update -self
```

If you are using the old approach and still having problems with TC, I would recommend you update to the new approach (see the second link below).

See here for more info:

- http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html
- http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore
- http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore

Comment: TeamCity ships with a NuGet Installer build step that handles the package restoration for you, just point it at the solution file. See this article for details: http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/08/nuget-package-restore-with-teamcity/

Comment: This step IS already included into my TeamCity - config. It also retrieves the packages